# Making section headers look like chapter headers

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I would like to make my section headers look like this with the `titlesec` package. Is there a good way to do that?

EDIT - I am using the scratcl document class.

[image]

Comment: assuming your document class (which you really should have stated) has chapters, `\let\section\chapter` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: do you also want them to affect the page style?

Comment: I am not sure but do you really want `Chapter 1` or isn't it rather `Section 1` and then the name of the section (`Introduction` here) that you want to get ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your document class has chapters, the simpler solution is to say

```
\let\section\chapter
```

as **David Carlisle** mentioned in his comment. After the edit, it is clear that the used class (`scrartcl`) has no chapters, so (as required) you can use this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\chaptername\ \thesection}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\section{A test chapter}
Some test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If each \section should begin on a page of its own, you might need to add

```
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}
```

or

```
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\cleardoublepage}
```

The above solution, however, this will just imitate some aspects (in particular, the title formatting), but not all of them, of a true `\chapter` in `book`, or `report`. Also, take into account that KOMA classes and `titlesec` package might not fully cooperate.